# How to get the full name of an android bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I use `startDiscovery()` and a `BroadcastReceiver` to search nearby `Bluetooth` device.

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            String btname = device.getName();
            }
        }
        if (action.equals(ActivityControlCenter.ACTIVITY_EXIT_ACTION)){
            finish();
        }
    }
};
```

As I need to use the `Bluetooth` name to transmit some message, so I set my `Bluetooth` name about 40 to 150 bytes (the maximum is 248). However, the `btname` I get from `device.getName()` is not the full name that I set.

How can I get the full name of the `Bluetooth` name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
// if device does not support Bluetooth
if(mBluetoothAdapter==null){
    Log.d(TAG,"device does not support bluetooth");
    return null;
}
String bluetoothname = mBluetoothAdapter.getName();
```

Comment: Sorry but you may misunderstand. I mean the bluetooth name of another android device

Comment: For example, I have two devices A and B. I set the bluetooth name of A in 100 bytes. I can just get the name of A 50 bytes in B.

Comment: I can get the name, but just a part of it.

Comment: @user3611977 any fix for getting the partial name?